# return a trie node in a search function

Tags: c, trie

I'm writing a program using trie. and my search function returns an integer, but I need it return a trie node.

```
struct TrieNode{
   struct TrieNode *children[ALPHABET_SIZE];
   int repeat;
   int groupNumber;
   int groupName;
   int  isLeaf;
};

int CHAR_TO_INDEX(int c){
   if(c >= 97 && c <= 122){
       c -= 97;
   }
   else if(c >= 65 && c <= 90){
       c = c - 65 + 32;
   }
   else
       return -1;
   return c;
}

int search(struct TrieNode *root, const char *key,int ask)
{
   int level;
   int length = strlen(key);
   int index;
   struct TrieNode *pCrawl = root;

   for (level = 0; level < length; level++)
   {
       index = CHAR_TO_INDEX(key[level]);
       if(index == -1)
           continue;

       if (!pCrawl->children[index])
           return 0;

       pCrawl = pCrawl->children[index];
    }

    if(ask == 0)
        return (pCrawl->repeat)*(pCrawl != NULL && pCrawl->isLeaf);
    return (pCrawl->groupNumber)*(pCrawl != NULL && pCrawl->isLeaf);
}
```

but when I want it return struct TrieNode ,it goes to wrong result, and if it returns struct TrieNode* ,it gets runtime error.

```
struct TrieNode search(struct TrieNode *root, const char *key)
{
   int level;
   int length = strlen(key);
   int index;
   struct TrieNode *pCrawl = root;

   for (level = 0; level < length; level++)
   {
       index = CHAR_TO_INDEX(key[level]);
       if(index == -1)
           continue;

       if (!pCrawl->children[index])
           return ;

       pCrawl = pCrawl->children[index];
   }
   return *pCrawl;
}
```

or

```
struct TrieNode *search(struct TrieNode *root, const char *key)
{
   int level;
   int length = strlen(key);
   int index;
   struct TrieNode *pCrawl = root;

   for (level = 0; level < length; level++)
   {
       index = CHAR_TO_INDEX(key[level]);
       if(index == -1)
           continue;

       if (!pCrawl->children[index])
           return ;

       pCrawl = pCrawl->children[index];
   }
   return pCrawl;
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with returning a `struct TrieNode`. But in your current example you have: `if (!pCrawl->children[index]) return ;` which is wrong as you don't return a `struct TrieNode` in that case

Comment: BTW `c = c - 65 + 32;` --> `c -= 'A';`

Comment: What is `ALPHABET_SIZE` ?